# assertFalse should pass when no arguments in method phpunit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

My Test includes the wp_verify_nonce and implemented that in OOP environment.
Now the problem is: If verifyNonce() has no arguemnts passed, then i want to expect return false due to the function:

```
verifyNonce():

     public function verifyNonce( $nonce ) {

          if( ! function_exists( 'wp_verify_nonce') || empty( $nonce ) || !is_string( $nonce ) )  return false; 

          return wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, $this->action );

     }
```

If $nonce is empty then it should return false since i passed this the if condition!

Now here i'm expecting that when there is no arguements passed, then it should return false:

```
testVerifyNonce():

public function testVerifyNonce() {

      $action        = 'my_action';
      $nonce         = '4832552f';

      $myWPNonce     = new test\MY_WP_Nonces( $action );

      \WP_Mock::userFunction( 'wp_verify_nonce', array( 

           'times'             =>   3,
           'return_in_order'   =>   array(false, 1, 2)

      ) );

      $this->assertFalse( $myWPNonce->verifyNonce() );

      $this->assertEquals( 1, $myWPNonce->verifyNonce( $nonce ) );

      $this->assertEquals( 2, $myWPNonce->verifyNonce( $nonce ) );

 }
```

Here's the output of my bash console:

```
PHPUnit 5.1.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..E....                                                             7 / 7 (100%)

Time: 206 ms, Memory: 8.00Mb

There was 1 error:

1) MYWPNonce_Test::testVerifyNonce
Missing argument 1 for Mywpnonces\src\wpnonce\MY_WP_Nonces::verifyNonce(), called in /mnt/c/Users/hm/Desktop/Github/Mywpnonces/src/tests/wpnonceTest.php on line 76 and defined

/mnt/c/Users/hm/Desktop/Github/Mywpnonces/src/wpnonce.php:37
/mnt/c/Users/hm/Desktop/Github/Mywpnonces/src/tests/wpnonceTest.php:76

FAILURES!
Tests: 7, Assertions: 6, Errors: 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPUnit tests your returning value of `$myWPNonce->verifyNonce()`. Before this can be accomplished you must pass the parameter, as it is defined in the method as mandatory parameter.

**PHPUnit does not test forgotten/missing parameters.** PHP itself validates this.

So pass something what should return false there as result.